# Python - after a certain if loop repeat a certain part of the code

Tags: python, for-loop, repeat

I'm writing a script for a CFD visualization programm which got an interface with python.
I created a generic dialog where the user can put in some values. Now I want to repeat that dialog if the input is false (which just means that one variable is bigger than the other):

```
items = []
items.append(['text',ITEM_TEXT,"Automatically save the evaluation in data file(s)\n",""])
items.append(['text',ITEM_TEXT,"Determine the range of timesteps that you want to save:",""])
items.append(['step_begin',ITEM_INT,"Start timestep:","Start timestep",first_step,first_step,timesteps])
items.append(['step_end',ITEM_INT,"End timestep:","End timestep",timesteps,first_step,timesteps])
a = CeiQtGenericDialog(items,None,"Save evaluation","Ok","Cancel")
ret = a.doit()

if (ret > 0):
    for i in a.getValues():
        if (i=='step_begin'):
            begin = a.getValue(i)
        if (i=='step_end'):
            end = a.getValue(i)

    if (begin > end):
        items2 = []
        items2.append(['text',ITEM_TEXT,"Start timestep must be smaller than end timestep!!",""])
        a = CeiQtGenericDialog(items2,None,"Error","Ok","Cancel")
        ret = a.doit()

        if (ret > 0):
            ????
```

In `a.getValues()` there are stored the values of the generic dialog before. Now in the last if I want to jump back to the generic dialog before. In other words I want to repeat the code starting from a certain line so the user can repeat entering "step_begin" and "step_end" in the generic dialog before, how is that possible?

EDIT/
if the user clicks OK in the generic dialog ret gets the value 1 if the user clicks cancel ret gets the value 0

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: sorry I'm new to python... but I think the identation is correct, at least python runs the code until the last if statement

Comment: Didnt you want to keep asking the user to input till the values are valid?

Comment: I thought that `a.getValue` is where user gives the input.

Comment: no sorry, that was probably not well explained! a.getValues() takes the values of the generic dialog before and gives them to my next function, loop or whatever

Comment: I edited my post and inserted what comes before my for loop. I want to come back to the part of `items = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a while loop as follows:

```
begin = 0
end = -1
ret = 1
while (begin > end and ret > 0):
    items = []
    items.append(['text',ITEM_TEXT,"Automatically save the evaluation in data file(s)\n",""])
    items.append(['text',ITEM_TEXT,"Determine the range of timesteps that you want to save:",""])
    items.append(['step_begin',ITEM_INT,"Start timestep:","Start timestep",first_step,first_step,timesteps])
    items.append(['step_end',ITEM_INT,"End timestep:","End timestep",timesteps,first_step,timesteps])
    a = CeiQtGenericDialog(items,None,"Save evaluation","Ok","Cancel")
    ret = a.doit()

    if (ret > 0):
        for i in a.getValues():
            if (i=='step_begin'):
                begin = a.getValue(i)
            if (i=='step_end'):
                end = a.getValue(i)

        if (begin > end):
            items2 = []
            items2.append(['text',ITEM_TEXT,"Start timestep must be smaller than end timestep!!",""])
            a = CeiQtGenericDialog(items2,None,"Error","Ok","Cancel")
            ret = a.doit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You should repeat whole this part while You don't get result You are expected for

```
while True:
    a = CeiQtGenericDialog(items,None,"Save evaluation","Ok","Cancel")
    ret = a.doit()

    if (ret < 0): 
        break # if cancel dialog will not proceed data analysis
    for i in a.getValues():
        if (i=='step_begin'):
            begin = a.getValue(i)
        if (i=='step_end'):
            end = a.getValue(i)

    if (begin < end):
        break # if everything is ok move out 
    items2 = []
    items2.append(['text',ITEM_TEXT,"Start timestep must be smaller than end timestep!!",""])
    a = CeiQtGenericDialog(items2,None,"Error","Ok","Cancel")
    ret = a.doit()
        if ret < 0:
           break # if cancel dialog will not proceed data analysis
```